# Luma theme less styles styles not showing

Tags: theme, less, luma-theme, less-compilation

I have a fresh Magento 2 install using the luma theme which i am happy to use. I have tried editing less files by moving them from

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_theme.less` to `design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_theme.less`

but my changes are not showing on the frontend. Changes in the vendor file however are. I have cleared my caches, recompiled etc but still no luck. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to edit the files in the vendor directory directly, as any changes made there will be overwritten when Magento is updated or when the theme is updated. Instead, you should create a new theme and override the files there.

Comment: I know and that is explained in my question and there is the issue that I’m having.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these steps:

1. Make sure that your custom theme is enabled in Magento by going to Content > Configuration in the admin panel, selecting your store view, and checking if your custom theme is selected as the design theme.
2. Check that your custom theme has been properly registered with Magento by going to app/design/frontend///theme.xml and verifying that the parent node is set to Magento/Luma and the media node is set to view.xml.
3. Verify that the file path in your custom theme is correct. Double-check that the file path and file name match exactly with the original file in the Luma theme directory.
4. Try running the command bin/magento setup:upgrade to ensure that your custom theme is properly registered with Magento.
5. Finally, if none of the above steps work, you can try manually deleting all files in the pub/static directory and running bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f again to regenerate the static files for your custom theme.

If none of these solutions work, there may be an issue with your Magento installation or server configuration. You could try reaching out to me or create a new instance and share SFTP with me so I can check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all this commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```